# Extract sequence using sequence ID in fasta file

Tags: python, sequence, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a fasta ID (`Q99424` in the example) and I need to extract the corresponding sequence for that ID. I am using `Bio` library for that which represent each record as below:

`SeqRecord(seq=Seq('MGSPVHRVSLGDTWSRQMHPDIESERYMQSFDVERLTNILDGGAQNTALRRKVE...SKL'), id='sp|Q99424|ACOX2_HUMAN', name='sp|Q99424|ACOX2_HUMAN', description='sp|Q99424|ACOX2_HUMAN', dbxrefs=[])`

I can iterate over every record and search but it is not the best way because I have more than 12000 records to search.

This is how we can iterate over all sequences:

```
for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"):
  name = record.name
  id = record.name.split("|")[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pyfaidx : https://pythonhosted.org/pyfaidx/
You can generate the fasta index ".fai" using this module or samtools, and then use pyfaidx's fetch function